# How spring-spanner's keep-alive for write-sessions works?

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm not sure why spring-spanner's keep-alive for write-sessions works without abort.

My understandings are the following:

- A write-session starts read-write transaction before it's actually used and retained in session pool.
- Keep-alive exec `select 1` for the the interval you specified in application.yaml (default is 30 min).
- Read-write transaction for spanner causes an abort if more than 10 seconds passed after the last sql is executed.

So I think it causes an abort after 10 seconds passed from the last keep-alive executed.
However, I haven't seen abort for that situation.

How does it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see how this is a little confusing, but there are actually two different things that could timeout and might need a keep-alive query in Cloud Spanner.

1. Read/write transactions will be aborted if they are **active** and left unused for more than 10 seconds. In order to keep it alive, you could ping it with a `SELECT 1` query. However: You should normally **NOT** do that, because you should try to keep your read/write transactions as short as possible. The confusion comes from the fact that a read/write transaction will only be considered **active** once it has executed **at least one** statement. So the prepared transactions in the session pool have only been started with a `BeginTransaction`, but they have not seen any statements yet. These are therefore **not started** and will not be aborted.
2. **Sessions** will timeout after 60 minutes. The `SELECT 1` keep-alive query in the session pool that is executed every 30 minutes is there to prevent **sessions** from timing out.

The next question now might be: What about the `SELECT 1` statements that are executed on the sessions in the pool that already have a read/write transaction prepared, won't those become active when the `SELECT 1` ping query is executed, and then be aborted after 10 seconds?

The answer to that is no. The `SELECT 1` ping queries are executed using a single-use read-only transaction. This will not affect the prepared read/write transaction on the same session, so both the session and the read/write transaction will remain valid.

The restriction that you cannot **execute** more than one transaction at the same time on a session only applies to multiple read/write transactions that are active at the same time.

---

EDIT: Added additional examples to show what is allowed and not allowed.

The following example uses the generated Java Spanner client (`com.google.cloud.spanner.v1.SpannerClient`) to show what is possible and not possible when it comes to executing multiple transactions on one session. All the statements below **except the last one** will succeed.

```java
SpannerClient client = SpannerClient.create();
// Create a session and a read/write transaction.
Session session = client.createSession(
    DatabaseName.of("my-project", "my-instance", "my-database"));
Transaction transaction = client.beginTransaction(session.getName(),
    TransactionOptions
      .newBuilder()
      .setReadWrite(ReadWrite.getDefaultInstance())
      .build());

// Execute a statement using a single-use read-only transaction.
client.executeSql(
    ExecuteSqlRequest
      .newBuilder()
      .setSession(session.getName())
      .setSql("SELECT * FROM SINGERS")
      .setTransaction(
          TransactionSelector.newBuilder().setSingleUse(
            TransactionOptions
              .newBuilder()
              .setReadOnly(ReadOnly.getDefaultInstance()).build())
          .build())
        .build());

// Execute a statement on the read/write transaction. This will activate
// the transaction.
client.executeSql(
    ExecuteSqlRequest
      .newBuilder()
      .setSession(session.getName())
      .setSql("SELECT * FROM SINGERS")
      .setTransaction(
          TransactionSelector
          .newBuilder()
          .setId(transaction.getId())
          .build())
      .build());

// Execute another statement using a single-use read-only transaction.
client.executeSql(
    ExecuteSqlRequest
      .newBuilder()
      .setSession(session.getName())
      .setSql("SELECT * FROM SINGERS")
      .setTransaction(
          TransactionSelector.newBuilder().setSingleUse(
            TransactionOptions
              .newBuilder()
              .setReadOnly(ReadOnly.getDefaultInstance()).build())
          .build())
        .build());

// Start a read-only transaction on the same session.
Transaction readOnlyTx = client.beginTransaction(session.getName(),
    TransactionOptions
      .newBuilder()
      .setReadOnly(
          ReadOnly
            .newBuilder()
            .setExactStaleness(Duration.newBuilder().setSeconds(10L).build())
            .build())
       .build());
// Execute a statement on the multi-use read-only transaction.
client.executeSql(
    ExecuteSqlRequest
      .newBuilder()
      .setSession(session.getName())
      .setSql("SELECT * FROM SINGERS")
      .setTransaction(
          TransactionSelector
            .newBuilder()
            .setId(readOnlyTx.getId())
            .build())
      .build());

// The initial read/write transaction is still valid.
client.executeSql(
    ExecuteSqlRequest
      .newBuilder()
      .setSession(session.getName())
      .setSql("SELECT * FROM SINGERS")
      .setTransaction(
          TransactionSelector
            .newBuilder()
            .setId(transaction.getId())
            .build())
      .build());

// Start another read/write transaction on the same session.
// This transaction has not been activated yet, as we have not
// executed any statements on it.
Transaction anotherTransaction = client.beginTransaction(session.getName(),
    TransactionOptions
      .newBuilder()
      .setReadWrite(ReadWrite.getDefaultInstance())
      .build());

// Execute another statement on the initial read/write transaction.
// This transaction is still usable even though we just created a
// new read/write transaction on the same session.
client.executeSql(
    ExecuteSqlRequest
      .newBuilder()
      .setSession(session.getName())
      .setSql("SELECT * FROM SINGERS")
      .setTransaction(
          TransactionSelector
          .newBuilder()
          .setId(transaction.getId())
          .build())
      .build());

// Now execute a statement on the second read/write transaction.
// This will silently invalidate the first read/write transaction.
client.executeSql(
    ExecuteSqlRequest
      .newBuilder()
      .setSession(session.getName())
      .setSql("SELECT * FROM SINGERS")
      .setTransaction(
          TransactionSelector
          .newBuilder()
          .setId(anotherTransaction.getId())
          .build())
      .build());

// Now try to execute a statement on the initial read/write transaction.
// Only this statement will fail because it has been invalidated by another
// read/write transaction on the same session.
client.executeSql(
    ExecuteSqlRequest
      .newBuilder()
      .setSession(session.getName())
      .setSql("SELECT * FROM SINGERS")
      .setTransaction(
          TransactionSelector
          .newBuilder()
          .setId(transaction.getId())
          .build())
      .build());
```

Comment: Thank you!
Then one more question arises: is it ok to make 2 transaction at a same time?

Comment: A write session begins read-write transaction then it's kept in a session pool, and as your answer, keep-alive is executed by sending `SELECT 1` ping using a single-use read-only transaction. It looks one session execute 2 transaction(one is read-write transaction, and another is single-use read-only transaction) at a same time.

Comment: But from [this document](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions) one session can have only 1 transaction at a same time.
Is it ok or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that is ok. I can see how that text is a little misleading: 'Sessions can execute only one transaction at a time.' The session is not 'executing' the read/write transaction (it has not yet been activated by a statement). So executing a single-use read-only transaction while the read/write transaction is prepared on the session is ok.

Comment: Are the following 2 items correct? [1] If read-write transaction has not been activated (=no statement has been sent), it's ok to start single-use transaction during the read-write transaction. [2] If read-write transaction is activated by sending at least one statement, it's not allowed to start single-use transaction during the read-write transaction.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little quick with that last reply. The limitation of only one (active) transaction on a session applies to read/write transactions. You may execute additional single-use and even multi-use read-only transactions on a session without invalidating a read/write transaction. I'll add some more detail to my answer above to show what is allowed and what is not.

Comment: That's so comprehensive! I understood, thanks!!

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer? That will make it easier for others to find it as well if they have a similar question.